# Module system in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, commonjs

I have a module in typescript like this:

```
let function test(){
//...
}
export default test;
```

and I want `tsc` to compile it to be like this:

```
let function test(){
    //...
    }
module.exports = test;
```

However, I found it compiles it like this:

```
let function test(){
        //...
        }
exports.default = test;
```

So I have to require it like this:

```
const test = require('xxx').default;
```

So how to solve this?

Comment: try - export = test; - when importing - import test = require("yourmodulename");

Comment: When you're using `export` to expose your module, why not use `import` to consume it?

Comment: @betadeveloper thanks a lot, it works for me.

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb I want to use commonjs module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how to solve this?

Use `export =`.

## Fixed code

```
let function test(){
//...
}
export = test;
```